# Find all continuous function $ \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{x}(f(t))^{2} d t=\frac{1}{x}\left(\int_{0}^{x} f(t) d t\right)^{2} $

Tags: calculus, integration

Find all continuous function $f:(0, \infty) \rightarrow(0, \infty) \ni f(1)=1$ and
$$
\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{x}(f(t))^{2} d t=\frac{1}{x}\left(\int_{0}^{x} f(t) d t\right)^{2}
$$

**My approach:-**

Let $ F(x)=\int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt$ and $G(x)=\int_{0}^{x}(f(t))^{2} dt$.

Since $f:(0, \infty) \rightarrow(0, \infty)$ we have $F(x)>0 (\forall x>0)$
Also, $\frac{1}{2} G(x)=\frac{1}{x}\{F(x)\}^{2},$ from the given condition on differentiation, we have
$$
\frac{1}{2} G^{\prime}(x)=\frac{1}{x} \cdot 2 F(x) \cdot F^{\prime}(x)-\frac{1}{x^{2}}(F(x))^{2}
$$
Next I am confused what to do??
Any suggestion or solution would be appreciated.

Comment: what about differentiate $G$ and $F$? I mean, note that $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a ^x h(t) dt=h(x)$ for any continuous function $h$, this is just the fundamental theorem of calculus

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the $x$ on over to the other side and differentiate:

$$\frac{x}{2}\int_0^x [f(t)]^2\:dt = \left(\int_0^x f(t)\:dt\right)^2$$

$$ \implies \frac{x}{2}[f(x)]^2 + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^x [f(t)]^2\:dt = 2f(x)\int_0^x f(t)\:dt$$

Then multiply both sides by $x$ and substitute in the first equation for the middle term:

$$\left(\int_0^x f(t)\:dt\right)^2 - 2xf(x)\int_0^x f(t)\:dt + \frac{x^2}{2}[f(x)]^2 = 0$$

Quadratic equation gives us

$$\int_0^x f(t)\:dt = xf(x) \pm \sqrt{x^2[f(x)]^2 - \frac{x^2}{2}[f(x)]^2} = \left(1 \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)xf(x)$$

since $x,f\in(0,\infty)$. One more derivative gives us a workable differential equation

$$f = \left(1 \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\Bigr(f + xf'\Bigr) \implies (1\pm \sqrt{2})xf' + f = 0$$

which has the solutions

$$f(x) = x^{-\frac{1}{1\pm\sqrt{2}}} = x^{1\pm\sqrt{2}}$$

both of which satisfy $f(1) = 1$. Both functions are locally integrable around $0$ so we must keep them both as solutions.